# Can an Azure ARM nested template be deployed with a mode of Complete?

Tags: azure, azure-resource-manager

All the examples have the mode of nested templates set to 'Incremental'.

When I set it to 'Complete', I get the following error:

```
error:   InvalidNestedDeploymentMode : Specified deployment mode 'Complete' is not supported for nested deployment 'shared'. Please see https://aka.ms/arm-deploy for usage details.
error:   Deployment validate failed.
error:   Error information has been recorded to /Users/.../.azure/azure.err
verbose: Error: Deployment validate failed.
```

I've tried running the deployment creation w/ both incremental and complete mode, getting the same error.

Wasn't sure if this was even possible - can't find any docs related to the error 'InvalidNestedDeploymentMode'.

Portion of the ARM template :

```
 {
  "name": "[concat('node', copyIndex())]",
  "type": "Microsoft.Resources/deployments",
  "apiVersion": "2015-01-01",
  "dependsOn": [
    "[resourceId('Microsoft.Resources/deployments', 'shared')]"
  ],
  "copy": {
    "name": "nodecopy",
    "count": "[parameters('vmCount')]"
  },
  "properties": {
    "mode": "Complete",
    "templateLink": {
      "uri": "...",
      "contentVersion": "1.0.0.0"
    }
 }
```

Comment: At the bottom of this page it says only the root template may be set to Complete:  https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/dn790564.aspx
"For nested templates, deployment mode Complete is only allowed on the root-level template"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Can an Azure ARM nested template be deployed with a mode of Complete?

Firstly, we could know **Incremental** and **Complete** mode that used to deploy resources from [this documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/dn790564.aspx).

[image]

Besides, as Andrew W said, only the root-level template is allowed Complete for the deployment mode. If you use Azure PowerShell with Resource Manager templates to deploy your resources to Azure and use `-Debug` parameter, you could see detailed error message.

[image]

Comment: In setting the root template to 'Complete' and omitting mode from nested templates, I would assume that only resources in the root template are treated as 'Complete', as all resources in nested templates are treated as 'Incremental'.

Comment: Is not using nested templates the  only way to get a fully 'Complete' mode deployment?

Comment: @DarinHoward I believe it's said that nested template doesn't support Complete mode.

Answer (score 0):

See the note under "[Link Templates for Deployment](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-resource-manager/templates/linked-templates)".

TL;DR: if your nested template targets the same resource group as the top level template and you deploy the top level template in "Complete" mode the nested template will be treated as being deployed in "Complete" mode but otherwise it will be deployed in "Incremental" mode.